# return more than 1 value after THEN statement used with CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, set, case

Following is my query:

```
UPDATE DSOPI_PERSON_ADDR_RULE ADDR
SET ADDR.DEPT_NAME =
  CASE
    WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line1),     'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
    AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
    THEN ADDR.SRC_ADDRESS_LINE1
    WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line2), 'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
    AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
    THEN ADDR.SRC_ADDRESS_LINE2
    WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line3), 'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
    AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
    THEN ADDR.SRC_ADDRESS_LINE3
    WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line4), 'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
    AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
    THEN ADDR.SRC_ADDRESS_LINE4
    ELSE NULL
 END;
```

What I would like to do is, when the case condition is true I would like to make the respective address lines NULL. Is there any way to achieve it with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to add additional `CASE` statements for each address field:

The code is duplicated, but this allows you to set the address lines to null when the condition is met.

```
UPDATE DSOPI_PERSON_ADDR_RULE ADDR
SET ADDR.DEPT_NAME =
   CASE
      WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line1),
         'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
         AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
         THEN ADDR.SRC_ADDRESS_LINE1
      WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line2), 
         'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
         AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
         THEN ADDR.SRC_ADDRESS_LINE2
      WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line3), 
         'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
         AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
         THEN ADDR.SRC_ADDRESS_LINE3
      WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line4), 
         'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
         AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
         THEN ADDR.SRC_ADDRESS_LINE4
      ELSE NULL
   END
   , ADDR.SRC_Address_Line1 =
        CASE
           WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line1),     
              'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
              AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
              THEN NULL
           ELSE ADDR.SRC_Address_Line1
        END
   , ADDR.SRC_Address_Line2 =
        CASE
           WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line2),     
              'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
              AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
              THEN NULL
           ELSE ADDR.SRC_Address_Line2
        END
   , ADDR.SRC_Address_Line3 =
        CASE
           WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line3),      
              'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
              AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
              THEN NULL
           ELSE ADDR.SRC_Address_Line3
        END
   , ADDR.SRC_Address_Line4 =
        CASE
           WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line4),     
              'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG')
              AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL
              THEN NULL
           ELSE ADDR.SRC_Address_Line4
        END;
```

Comment: Just a thought: Wouldn't this method take twice the time to execute the query?

Comment: You would have to test that out in your environment.  I am normally in SQL Server, and similar operations (CASE statements in the ORDER BY) are not calculated multiple times within the query, so I would expect Oracle to behave similarly.

Answer (score 1):

So you would like to set src_address_line1 NULL if the first WHEN condition is true, and so on? In this case I'd do this:

```
UPDATE DSOPI_PERSON_ADDR_RULE ADDR

SET 
addr.src_address_line1 = 
CASE WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line1), 'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG') 
AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL 
THEN NULL ELSE addr.src_address_line1 END, 

addr.src_address_line2 = 
CASE WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line2), 'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG') 
AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL 
THEN NULL ELSE addr.src_address_line2 END, 

addr.src_address_line3 = 
CASE WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line3), 'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG') 
AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL 
THEN NULL ELSE addr.src_address_line3 END, 

addr.src_address_line4 = 
CASE WHEN regexp_like (UPPER(addr.src_address_line4), 'DEP|DPT$|ABT|DIP.|DIPART|AFDEL|AVDEL|AVD.|DIV|PGRD|PGP|PPG') 
AND ADDR.ORG_NAME IS NOT NULL 
THEN NULL ELSE addr.src_address_line4 END;
```